# How to migrate existing visualforce page to lighting

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

what kind of preoccupation steps need for migrate existing visualforce page to Lightning

Answer (score 1):

According to the Salesforce's documentation:

> With some important exceptions, Visualforce “just works” in Lightning Experience. If you’ve written Visualforce apps for your organization, you can expect that they work whether your users access them in Lightning Experience or Salesforce Classic.
>
> If your Visualforce pages use the built-in standard components, their look-and-feel matches Salesforce Classic, whether your users access them in Lightning Experience or Salesforce Classic. If you want your pages to match the Lightning Experience styling, you have some work to do.
>
> If your Visualforce pages make use of JavaScript, there are things you need to check. Visualforce doesn’t “own” the whole page when shown in Lightning Experience, and because of that your JavaScript code needs to play by some new rules.
>
> There are other things that have changed about how Visualforce runs when it’s running inside Lightning Experience. For the most part, these are turning the “just works” crank, but you’ll want to be aware of them all the same.

I recommand you to follow the [Visualforce et Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_visualforce) course on Salesforce's Trailhead website.